# How does liquibase select a schema if it is not explicitly specified?

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

I would like to use a `columnExists` precondition for my changeset, 
but specifying an exact schema is not possible since we gonna run the thing on multiple environments, and schema names might differ.

The question is, will the schema liquibase chooses be equivalent of

```
select sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA') from dual;
```

We are talking about Oracle here if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle there is a one-to-one relationship between user and schema.

The user account you use to log into Oracle is the default schema unless you have actively changed it in the session.

I was going to answer "just leave out the schema" until I saw that Liquibase requires the `schemaName` for the `columnExists` precondition (which is kind of stupid I think)

So you can't really use `columnExists`, and you will need a `<sqlCheck>` instead:

```
<preConditions onFail="HALT">
  <sqlCheck expectedResult="1">
    select count(*) 
    from user_tab_columns 
    where column_name = 'SOME_COLUMN' 
      and table_name = 'SOME_TABLE'
  </sqlCheck>
</preConditions>
```

`user_tab_columns` contains the columns of the tables the current user **owns** (i.e. created).

Comment: Liquibase does not actually require this schemaName parameter - you can leave it out. Not sure why it says it is required in their docs, but I'm pretty sure that columnExists and other preconditions work without schema being specified.

Comment: @gore_obsessed: if that is the case, then just leave it out and use `columnExists` I would assume that Liquibase then uses the "current schema" which is the same as the current user.

Comment: well I kinda assumed that too, but was not 100% sure so decided to ask this question :)